# Elsarticle - Abstract two columns wide

Tags: elsarticle

I am currently trying to create an article in elsarticle style, twocolumn. The title and text end up in two columns, the abstract however is made two columns wide. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Obviously I want my abstract to also be only in the first column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,preprint]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \journal{TexExchange}

 \begin{document}

   \begin{frontmatter}

     \title{Two-column abstract}

     \begin{abstract} 
       \lipsum[1]
     \end{abstract}

     \begin{keyword}
       abstract
     \end{keyword}

  \end{frontmatter}

 \section{Outline}
   \lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the style used by `elsarticle`, which is for submissions to Elsevier journals. You shouldn't modify the behavior.

Comment: Greg, I did not know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the source the only way I can see to get a sensible output from two column in preprint style is to put the `frontmatter` into the optional argument of an explicit `\twocolumn`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,preprint]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \journal{TexExchange}

 \begin{document}

\twocolumn[{\begin{frontmatter}

     \title{Two-column abstract}

     \begin{abstract} 
       \lipsum[1]
     \end{abstract}

     \begin{keyword}
       abstract
     \end{keyword}

  \end{frontmatter}
}]
 \section{Outline}
   \lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Or you can correct the width locally within a one-column frontmatter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,preprint]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \journal{TexExchange}

 \begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\setlength\textwidth\columnwidth
     \title{Two-column abstract}

     \begin{abstract} 
       \lipsum[1]
     \end{abstract}

     \begin{keyword}
       abstract
     \end{keyword}

  \end{frontmatter}

 \section{Outline}
   \lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response David. Do you mean that it won't work to put title and abstract both in the first column only? Or should I use a different option than preprint?

Comment: @SimonApers I added a second version

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `elsarticle`, section 12

> The authors can format their submission to the page size and margins of their preferred journal. `elsarticle` provides four class options for the same. But it does not mean that using these options you can emulate the exact page layout of the final print copy.
>
> `1p`: 1+ journals with a text area of 384pt × 562pt or 13.5cm × 19.75cm or 5.3in × 7.78in, single column style only.
>
> `3p`: 3+ journals with a text area of 468pt × 622pt or 16.45cm × 21.9cm or 6.5in × 8.6in, single column style.
>
> `twocolumn`: should be used along with `3p` option if the journal is 3+ with the same text area as above, but double column style.
>
> `5p`: 5+ with text area of 522pt × 682pt or 18.35cm × 24cm or 7.22in × 9.45in, double column style only.
>
> Following pages have the clippings of different parts of the title page of different journal models typeset in final format.
>
> Model 1+ and 3+ will have the same look and feel in the typeset copy when presented in this document. That is also the case with the double column 3+ and 5+ journal article pages. The only difference will be wider text width of higher models. Therefore we will look at the different portions of a typical single column journal page and that of a double column article in the final format.

So either you use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,preprint,3p]{elsarticle}
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,preprint,5p]{elsarticle}
```

The output is very similar, so I show only the one with the first document class line.

[image]