# Issue with overwritten abstract in two-column elsarticle

Tags: two-column, abstract, elsarticle, front-matter

I have a question related to [Elsarticle - Abstract two columns wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211148/elsarticle-abstract-two-columns-wide). I would like an output like the first one in David Carlisle's answer, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on the Answer.

The code published there:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\journal{TexExchange}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}
    \title{Two-column abstract}
    \begin{abstract} 
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{keyword}
      abstract
    \end{keyword}
 \end{frontmatter}
\section{Outline}
  \lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

gives me:

[image: Output of the code above]

Which is what I get for my actual article too. Now obviously that is useless and what I really want is:

[image: Desired result]

As per the answer to the linked question. (I need to use the `elsarticle` class with two columns for obvious reasons)

Comment: I have added an answer to the other question.

Comment: Yes, the answer was what i was looking after, I had read the bit about 1p, 3p and 5p but did not know that this would be the effect. Anyway I thought the anwer was clearer under this question, but has since been moved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question was very much similar so it's better not to duplicate information. Having a few pointers to the same question can even ease search, so also questions marked as duplicate have their value.