# How to put the abstract above two column paper (elsarticle)?

Tags: two-column, elsarticle, abstract

Using the below code I get the following output. How can I bring item 12 onwards down such that the abstract is not include in the 2 column section?

```
\documentclass[review, twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}

%\nolinenumbers

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{PAPER TITLE\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
[ABSTRACT TO BE WRITTEN]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\item item 1
\end{enumerate}

\newpage




\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239929/1952. You need to add `3p` to class options or don't write `twocolumn` and replace it for `5p`

Comment: Much appreciated thank you this is exactly what I was looking for